# Representing date format for three letter month in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How do I represent a 3 letter month date format in python such as the following:

Jan 16, 2012

I know for January 16, 2012 the format is %B %d,%Y. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's the three letter month format `%b`:

```
In [37]: datetime.strptime('Jan 16, 2012', '%b %d, %Y')
Out[37]: datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 16, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Im finding with stackoverflow that I now go to the second answer without even looking at the first one :-) thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

```
date_str = 'Jan 16, 2012'
date_components = date_str.split(' ')
date_components[0] = date_components[0][:3]
return ' '.join(date_components)
```

Comment: You will use datetime.strptime(date_str , '%b %d, %Y')

Answer (score 0):

present_day = datetime.today()

present_day_string = present_day.strftime("%-d")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).